# Where should I place an adverb in 3. conditional?

Tags: adverbs, conditional-constructions

> I surely would have traveled around the world if I had had a lot of
>   money.

Is the adverb *surely* in the right place? If not where should it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I surely would have travelled around the world if I had a lot of money.

First off, the sentence is conditional 3, not 2.

As for the adverb surely, it's in the right place.

You can also put it at the beginning of the main clause or after the first auxiliary would as follows:

Surely I would have travelled......".

I would surely have travelled......".